# rails 4 simple fragment caching doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed the following in config/enviornments/development to:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

I have the following view:

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>

<% cache do %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
   <div class="entry">
     <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
     <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
     <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
     <div class="price_line">
       <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
     </div>
   </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I load the page, then remove the title and then load page again and the title disappears from the page. With caching I expect it to show the title. Is there any step I am missing?

EDIT:

IN rails guide example:

```
<% Order.find_recent.each do |o| %>
  <%= o.buyer.name %> bought <%= o.product.name %>
<% end %>

<% cache do %>
  All available products:
  <% Product.all.each do |p| %>
    <%= link_to p.name, product_url(p) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

They seem to do the same/similar type of cache. I have tried some of their examples and nothing caches.

Comment: When you remove the title, a new cache gets created which is why you don't see it in the view.

Comment: @vee How would I cause it to use the same cache?

Comment: Please take a look at [`fragment caching`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching), especially the last two paragraphs.

Comment: @vee I looked at that document and they seem to be doing similar caching. I even tried using their examples and it didn't cache either. I must be doing something wrong with my setup somewhere.

Comment: What do you have for `cache_store` configuration?  Could you try setting it to `:file_store`, and check your `tmp/cache` directory for cached data?  I would begin by clearing the cache first.

Comment: @vee Just tried this. I cleared it out and when I refreshed the 1st and 2nd time new caches were created each time. Do you think the file modify date causes this?

Comment: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/russian-doll-caching-cache-digests-rails-4-countdown-to-2013